# Do I have to implement Stop method in a windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I'm looking at some legacy code in the form of a Windows service.

I've noticed that in their OnStop() method, they simply write to the event log, however there is no object clean-up or control of terminating any threads.  There are 2 background threads which are started on startup of the service so I'm left wondering, does this service actually stop?  And, if it does, are the threads closed down correctly?

Is the stop method physically terminating the process or is it only a logical stop, which if left not implemented doesn't actually do anything?

Answer (score 1):

The [OnStop()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstop.aspx) method is called when the service is stopped you can clear the objects and stop the threads etc here. If your thread do not need any thing special to do when service is stopped then you can leave the OnStop method

> OnStop is expected to be overridden in the derived class. For the
>   service to be useful, OnStart and OnStop should both be implemented in
>   your service class, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstop.aspx)

Comment: What if the thread has a blocking call such as a TcpListener listening for clients?

Comment: OnStop will be call on different thread how TcpListener thread can block it?

Comment: So OnStop would terminate the parent thread and child threads irrespective of whether the child thread is blocking?

Comment: OnStop is call when your service is stopped e.g. stopped from services management console.

Answer (score 1):

Stopping a service is not the same thing as terminating it.  It is a *logical* condition.  The admin will have an expectation that you'll stop doing whatever you do after the service was started.  So your service doesn't get in the way of whatever he's going to do next.  Say backing up a directory or editing a config file, etcetera.

You don't *have* to actually implement this.  Nor does Windows enforce it, the service manager takes your word for it when you report that you stopped and doesn't otherwise prevent you from doing anything.  But of course at a risk of confuzzling the admin.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question Its terminating the process. 
But it must implement the clean up code because a common scenario will be you left the Thread running on Service and it gets stopped but the Process will still be there because of the Thread. I had same experience with left thread so we should implement the Thread clean up code and other resources which can prevent the Process from Terminating.

Comment: I just tested it (see the code in my answer), it terminated the service without issue when I had a thread running. The only time I ever had issues on stopping is if you had a operation in the `OnStop` that took a long time to complete.

Comment: What happened to your post scott?

Comment: I did verify again with your code Service will be stopped but the process will still be running. please stop the service and check in Task Manager you will see the process exists